# How to combine similar values into single value dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that includes languages of codes.

The head of dataframe;

```
    repo_id language
0   2519612 JavaScript
1   1519634 C   
2   8534335 C++ 
3   6719676 LiveScript  
4   1519234 C#
5   3234554 Python
6   3234554 Julia
7   3234554 Elm
8   3234554 Gosu
```

I want to combine similar language into single one.

For example,

"C, C++ and C#" consolidate into "C"

"LiveScript, JavaScript, .." consolidate into "JavaScript"

"Julia, Elm, Gosu" consolidate into "Other"

"Python" stay as "Python"

Desired output is;

```
    repo_id language
0   2519612 JavaScript
1   1519634 C   
2   8534335 C   
3   6719676 JavaScript  
4   1519234 C
5   3234554 Python
6   3234554 Other
7   3234554 Other
8   3234554 Other
```

Bad Solution;

```
df.loc[df['language'] == 'C++', 'language'] = 'C'
df.loc[df['language'] == 'C#', 'language'] = 'C'
```

I don't want to change labels individually, How can I do it easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:
Use apply function with a lambda function to check the language and then update the language column as follows

```
   df['language'] = df['language'].apply(lambda x: 'C' if x in ['C', 'C#', 'C++'] else 'JavaScript')
```

Desired output is:

```
        repo_id     language
0   2519670     JavaScript
1   2519670     C
2   2519670     C
3   2519670     JavaScript
4   2519670     C
```

Modify your function as follow

```
dic = {'repo_id':[2519670, 2519670,2519670, 2519670, 2519670, 2519670, 2519670,2519670, 2519670, 2519670], 
       'language':['JavaScript', "C++", "C", 'LiveScript', 'C#', 'Python', 'Julia', 'Elm', 'Gosu', 'Python'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
    repo_id     language
0   2519670     JavaScript
1   2519670     C++
2   2519670     C
3   2519670     LiveScript
4   2519670     C#
5   2519670     Python
6   2519670     Julia
7   2519670     Elm
8   2519670     Gosu
```

Then apply the following function:

```
df['language'] = df['language'].apply(lambda x: 'C' if x in ['C', 'C#', 'C++'] else ('JavaScript' if x in ['JavaScript', 'LiveScript'] else ('Python' if x in ['Python'] else 'Other')))
df
```

Desired output

```
repo_id     language
0   2519670     JavaScript
1   2519670     C
2   2519670     C
3   2519670     JavaScript
4   2519670     C
5   2519670     Python
6   2519670     Other
7   2519670     Other
8   2519670     Other
9   2519670     Python
```

Comment: I have more than two conditions. I removed the else statement, it gives error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @babeyh apply the above modified function again